Display buttons from checkbox
I have a database with different gym exercises, I'm trying to make a leaderboard for each one, and I want something like a checkbox form that takes all the exercises from  my database and adds them as check buttons, and as you check them, I want them to appear the the navbar as options to click.
I'm doing it manually but I want it to be dynamic and I have no idea how to do it.
I'm using bootstrap 5 and this is what I have now, I'd be thankful for any tips or suggestions


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarCategories">
  <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbar">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#squats" class="nav-link" style="color: #c5c6c8;">Squats</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#deadlifts" class="nav-link" style="color: #c5c6c8;">Deadlifts</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#benchpress" class="nav-link" style="color: #c5c6c8;">Bench Press</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#overheadpress" class="nav-link" style="color: #c5c6c8;">Overhead Press</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="nav-link btn btn-primry dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" style="color: #c5c6c8;">Add favorite</button></li>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <form id="checkform">
          <input type="checkbox" id="benchpress" name="benchpress" value="Bench Press">
          <label for="benchpress">Bench Press</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="deadlift" name="deadlift" value="Deadlifts">
          <label for="deadlift">Deadlifts</label><br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="overheadpress" name="overheadpress" value="Overhead Press">
          <label for="overheadpress">Overhead Press</label><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>




Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a div between 

To make your checkbox form dynamic and automatically generate the navbar options based on the exercises in your database, you'll need to use a server-side scripting language like PHP or JavaScript. Here's a basic approach using JavaScript:

Fetch the list of exercises from your database.
Dynamically generate the checkbox form based on the fetched data.
Use JavaScript to handle form submission and dynamically update the navbar based on the selected exercises.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarCategories">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbar">
        <!-- Navbar options will be dynamically added here -->
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="nav-link btn btn-primry dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" style="color: #c5c6c8;">Add favorite</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="exerciseList">
                <!-- Checkbox form will be dynamically added here -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    // Simulated list of exercises (replace this with data from your database)
    const exercises = ['Squats', 'Deadlifts', 'Bench Press', 'Overhead Press'];

    // Function to dynamically generate the checkbox form
    function generateCheckboxForm() {
        const exerciseList = document.getElementById('exerciseList');
        exerciseList.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content

        exercises.forEach(exercise => {
            const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
            checkbox.id = exercise.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '');
            checkbox.name = 'exercise';
            checkbox.value = exercise;
            
            const label = document.createElement('label');
            label.htmlFor = checkbox.id;
            label.textContent = exercise;

            const br = document.createElement('br');

            exerciseList.appendChild(checkbox);
            exerciseList.appendChild(label);
            exerciseList.appendChild(br);
        });
    }

    // Call the function to generate the checkbox form
    generateCheckboxForm();

    // Function to handle form submission
    document.getElementById('checkform').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior

        const selectedExercises = [];
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="exercise"]:checked');
        checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
            selectedExercises.push(checkbox.value);
        });

        // Update the navbar options based on the selected exercises
        const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
        navbar.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing navbar options

        selectedExercises.forEach(exercise => {
            const listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.classList.add('nav-item');
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = '#' + exercise.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '');
            link.classList.add('nav-link');
            link.textContent = exercise;
            listItem.appendChild(link);
            navbar.appendChild(listItem);
        });
    });
</script>

If you give more details then it will be more helpful to answer your question. Details like backend technology, how you making API calls etc.
Anyways Remember to replace the exercises array with actual data fetched from your database using AJAX or any server-side scripting language.

Im using php to connect to the database, for the login.
Im already using AJAX and js, as of right now im generating new posts when at the bottom of the page, the idea is to have videos os the exercises tied to the leaderboard.
Not using any apis at the moment

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a div between 
